# IntelliJ select from start to line

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

I have opened a log file in IntelliJ, and I need to select from start to line 11055. How can I do from IDE? Is there some shortcut/command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way... not optimal, but at least it works.

1. Go the line where you want to finish selecting (11055 in my case)
2. Move to file start with the lateral bar
3. Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click on file start.

Answer (score 0):

Try to point the cursor at line 11055 and use `Page Up with Selection` action.

Shortcut may depend on the used OS. Check [Keymap](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-keymap.html) settings to find the needed keybinding:

[image]

Comment: I need to select from line to start, not only one page